# How to display result from calculator on focused textview on Android

Tags: android, textview, focus

I have a calculator input which displays the result in a textview.

I have two textviews and I want to display the result depending on which textview I clicked on, something like setting a focus and depending which textview was clicked, showing the calculator operation there.

I put

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

but this sets the textviews as edit text and I do not want it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the texviews as edittext and block user input using

```
edt1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
edt2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

then, based on the focus, set the result

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
                if(edt1.hasFocus()){
                    aux=aux+1;
                    edt1.setText(result);
                }
                if (edt2.hasFocus()){
                    aux = aux+1;
                    edt2.setText(result);
                }
            }
        });
```